# mixitup show all/none or choose one yourself

Tags: jquery

Are there any users of this filter that know how to change these settings.
At the moment i`m using it to show 4 different food menu pictures.
When you scroll down at the menu section it currently show all the item,
While i would like for it to only show the lunch menu and the other when you click on them.
I found this documentation for it but i quess im doing something wrong

```
$('#Container').mixItUp({
    load: {
        filter: '.category-1'
    }
});
```

Please correct me if i'm wrong but that is javascript right?
Do i create a new js file for this, Because i can't seem to find this part in the mixitup.js

This is my html

```
                          <section class="description_content">
    <div class="limit"> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="w">

                    <ul id="filter-list" class="clearfix">
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="breakfast">Lunch</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="special">Dinner</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="desert">Diversen</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="dinner">Nagerechten</li>
                    </ul><!-- @end #filter-list -->    
                    <ul class="row" id="portfolio">
                        <li class="item breakfast"><img src="images/lunch.jpg" alt="Food" >

                            <li class="item special"><img src="images/dinner.jpg" alt="Food" >
```

```
                        </li>
```

```
                        </li>

                     </ul><!-- @end #portfolio -->
                </div><!-- @end #w -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</section>
```

This is under my footer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
                    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') ==         this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                        var target = $(this.hash);
                          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' +     this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                    if (target.length) {
                        $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: target.offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                      return false;
                    }  
                }
            });
        });

    </script>


    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#portfolio').mixitup({
                targetSelector: '.item',
                transitionSpeed: 450
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly found the answer. In the .js file there is a part that says:

```
showOnLoad:"all"
```

Just change that to `"none"` or the file name of the pic you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

This is jQuery , Jquery is a library predefined in javascript , so if u want to use this piece of code you need to include jQUERY  in head section of your page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: including api alone would not help you also need to include mixitup jquery files similar to the one above link it and the functions should work , and remember #Container will be replaced by the id of the element you want to provide functionality read more here https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/docs/

Comment: I found that line under my footer. <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> </script>   .Should i replace that for your script src? and then make a new .js file with the code im my first post?

Comment: if you are using google chrome can you , right click open inspect element and click the console option , once you have it open click the menu , the errors will be shown there in console , then we can see why the errors are there , you have got all files needed for it to work and you donot need an additional js file , the code should work even inside the script tags

Comment: file:///C:/Users/fixed/Documents/gasthuys/css/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.  Thats the only thing thats in console option but it does not change when i click on menu or any other button

Comment: i think what you are trying to do is show the panel on click , what you can do is hide the elemnts by default and then display them when a button or something is clicked , step 1 hide the elements first set display : none in css for the elements and then set the onclcik function on the element you are displaying first  ex <button onclick="show()"></button> create function show in javascript and put this code http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp if all goes well when clicked the display none elemnts should appear as their property is changed to now

Comment: yes then set onlcik on lunch elemnt and display none in css for others , when a user will click on lunch the hidden elements will appear and your job is done

Comment: Thanks for your time, im kinda new to all this. This is gonna be my first site:) it`s gonna take me a while to understand how to do what you said.Will update when i think i tried it correct thanks

Comment: I cant seems to get this to work, no matter what i do all the menus keep showing by default. i quess its not that bad so ill just leave it like that, thanks for all the effort